# knockout js selected option

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a select tag in my html with knockout js binding.

```
<select class="form-control " data-bind="options: loanTimesBorrower,
   optionsText: loanTimesBorrower(),
   value: loanTimeBorrower,
   selectedOptions: loanTimesBorrowerini,
   optionsCaption: 'Choose dates'">
</select>
```

Instead of choose date I want to show the default value as 180, since I have a array which stores this loantime as 180 days, 360 days etc.

this is the array

```
self.loanTimesBorrower = ko.observableArray();
self.loanTimesBorrowerini = ko.observableArray(self.loanTimesBorrower()[0]);
```

and I get this array populated by a foreach loop which is getting the loantimes from db like this.

```
$.each(items.investTimes, function (index, item) {
  self.loanTimesBorrower.push(item.Loantime);
});
```

So I am not sure how the default value can be put as 180 instead of choose dates

Comment: Why do you use the optionsCaption parameter if you don't want to show it?

Comment: So you want to have something selected by default? If you don't want to start with a "nothing selected" option then why do you make it possible in the first place? If you don't add an `optionsCaption` binding then there will be no null option. The purpse of adding a "nothing selected" UX-wise is usually to indicate to the user that there is no default value, (s)he should choose one manually.

Comment: @AlexanderVogt well I thought it wouldnt matter even if it was there or not.

Comment: @AlexanderVogt yea it works after I removed it, Thanks! I dint think it would make a difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove
`optionsCaption: 'Choose dates'`
It would default to the option you provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this:

```
<select id="selectDate" class="form-control " data-bind="options: loanTimesBorrower,
   optionsText: loanTimesBorrower(),
   value: loanTimeBorrower,
   selectedOptions: loanTimeBorrower[0],
   optionsAfterRender: $root.setDefaultDate">
</select>
```

And in your javascript you can do something like:

```
    self.setDefaultDate= function (option, object) {
        if (typeof object !== "undefined" && object !== null) {
            if(object.value === 180) {
                $("#selectDate").find(option).prop('selected', true);
            }
        }
    };
```

if you show me what the object in your array looks like I can edit the answer for a better fit. But that should help you to find your way